# how to execute timing at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am now making the sorting function using jquery.

By clicking each button, assigned contents are shown with scaling animation.
However, when some sorting buttons are clicked each ones quickly, the timing for showing of some contents is not right.

For example, if clicking `btn-sortAll` right after clicking `btn-sort03`, `sort03` contents appears a little late.
How can I fix them?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.sort-btn li').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      let btnname = $(this).attr("class").substring(4).toLowerCase();
      let classname = '.';
      classname += btnname; //. + btnname
      $('.sort-content > div').hide();

      setTimeout(function() { // to wait to hide, and to avoide first content appear quickly
        if (btnname == 'sortall') {
          $('.sort-content > div').fadeIn(500);
        } else {
          $('.sort-content div:not(classname)').hide();
          $(classname).fadeIn(500);
        }
      }, 100);

    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sort-btn {
  display: flex;
}

.sort-btn li {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.sort-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.sort-content>div {
  width: 32vw;
  margin: .5vw;
  background: #9ad0e4;
  animation: scale .8s ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sort-btn">
  <li class="btn-sort01">btn-sort01</li>
  <li class="btn-sort02">btn-sort02</li>
  <li class="btn-sort03">btn-sort03</li>
  <li class="btn-sortAll">btn-sortAll</li>
</ul>
<div class="sort-content">
  <div class="sort01">sort01</div>
  <div class="sort03">sort03<br>sort03<br>sort03</div>
  <div class="sort02">sort02</div>
  <div class="sort02">sort02<br>sort02<br>sort02<br>sort02</div>
  <div class="sort01">sort01<br>sort01<br>sort01<br>sort01<br>sort01</div>
  <div class="sort03">sort03<br>sort03</div>
  <div class="sort01">sort01</div>
  <div class="sort01">sort01<br>sort01<br>sort01<br>sort01</div>
  <div class="sort02">sort02<br>sort02</div>
  <div class="sort01">sort01<br>sort01</div>
  <div class="sort03">sort03</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/). It takes two arguments: first clears queued animation (from multiple clicks) and the second to end it to start the next one. Set both options to true and attach to elements before the `.fade()` as in the example below.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.sort-btn li').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      let btnname = $(this).attr("class").substring(4).toLowerCase();
      let classname = '.';
      classname += btnname; //. + btnname
      $('.sort-content > div').hide();

      setTimeout(function() { // to wait to hide, and to avoide first content appear quickly
        if (btnname == 'sortall') {
          $('.sort-content > div').stop(true, true).fadeIn(500);
        } else {
          $('.sort-content div:not(classname)').hide();
          $(classname).stop(true, true).fadeIn(500);
        }
      }, 100);

    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sort-btn {
  display: flex;
}

.sort-btn li {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.sort-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.sort-content>div {
  width: 32vw;
  margin: .5vw;
  background: #9ad0e4;
  animation: scale .8s ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sort-btn">
  <li class="btn-sort01">btn-sort01</li>
  <li class="btn-sort02">btn-sort02</li>
  <li class="btn-sort03">btn-sort03</li>
  <li class="btn-sortAll">btn-sortAll</li>
</ul>
<div class="sort-content">
  <div class="sort01">sort01</div>
  <div class="sort03">sort03<br>sort03<br>sort03</div>
  <div class="sort02">sort02</div>
  <div class="sort02">sort02<br>sort02<br>sort02<br>sort02</div>
  <div class="sort01">sort01<br>sort01<br>sort01<br>sort01<br>sort01</div>
  <div class="sort03">sort03<br>sort03</div>
  <div class="sort01">sort01</div>
  <div class="sort01">sort01<br>sort01<br>sort01<br>sort01</div>
  <div class="sort02">sort02<br>sort02</div>
  <div class="sort01">sort01<br>sort01</div>
  <div class="sort03">sort03</div>
</div>
```